# OnBlur Validation Requires Onsubmit Button to Be Clicked Twice in Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, onsubmit, onblur

I have a form which validates password null/blank or not using onblur. And I use a submit button to submit the form.  However the submit button needs to be clicked twice before to work.  It does not work on the first click after something has been filled in the password box.  Below is the code.

With respect to Jquery, I require solution in pure Javascript.

I have tried onkeyup, but that is not a good solution as it will put strain on system, and server (for ajax).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <script>

      var error_user_password = false;

      function checkpw(){

        var user_password = document.forms["joinform"]["user_password"].value;
        if (user_password == null || user_password == "") {
          text = "Password : Required";
          document.getElementById("errormsg4").innerHTML = text;
          error_user_password = false;

        } else {
          document.getElementById("errormsg4").innerHTML = "";
          error_user_password = true;

        }
      }

      function submitall() {

        checkpw()
        if(error_user_password == false) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true
        }
      }
    </script>

  </body>
  <form id="joinform" method="post" name="joinform" action="#hello" onsubmit="return submitall()" >
    <h2>Join</h2>

    <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password" placeholder="Password" onblur="checkpw()"  />
    <div class ="errormsg" id ="errormsg4"></div><br>
    <input type="submit" name="join" id="join" value="Submit"   ><br><br>

  </form>

</html>
```

Comment: You could call checkpw() in submitall()? So it's always checked right before you decide to submit (as well as on blur).

Comment: Why calling another `validatepassword()`? Call same function for both `onblur` and form `submit` and return validation `true` or `false`. Also, better to use `onchange` than `onblur` on input (change occurs before blur).

Comment: @skobaljic I have multiple functions like checkpw() which I call in submitall(), the code I have posted is for simplicity.

Comment: @BobBrinks sorry there was an error in the code, in function submitall() - validatepassword() should be checkpw(), hence I am calling checkpw() in submitall() but it is not working.  I have fixed the code above.

Comment: It seems that your reluctance to use something like keyup or input as a triggering event may be premature optimization.  Are you actually making an ajax call for validation each time?

Comment: @FissureKing Yes, I have two ajax calls on this form, I intend to use this validation on other forms which may have multiple ajax, and 1 million rows in mysql database.

Comment: @DragonFire regardless of how many records you have in your database, your workflow seems a bit... archaic here.  You should provide validation to your users as they type, not after they've moved on.  Use oninput and write some kind of throttling function to ensure you aren't overloading your back end.

Comment: @FissureKing you are right, I am new to javascript, that is why my code my not be very elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OnBlur Validation Requires Onsubmit Button to Be Clicked Twice in Pure Javascript

This happens because the blur event is captured from the onblur event handler and not bubbled to the form submit button.

A full javaScript solution is based on:

- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener)
- [activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement): inside the blur event I check after 10 milliseconds if the submit button get the focus.

My snippet:

```js
var error_user_password = false;

function checkpw(ele, e){
  var user_password = document.forms["joinform"]["user_password"].value;

  if (user_password == null || user_password == "") {
    text = "Password : Required";
    document.getElementById("errormsg4").innerHTML = text;
    error_user_password = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("errormsg4").innerHTML = "";
    error_user_password = true;
  }
}

function submitall(ele, e) {
  checkpw();

  if(error_user_password == false) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    console.log('form submitted');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('user_password').addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    checkpw(this, e);
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (document.activeElement.id == 'join') {
        document.activeElement.click();
      }
    }, 10);
  }, false);
  document.getElementById('joinform').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    submitall(this, e);
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<form id="joinform" method="post" name="joinform" action="#hello">
    <h2>Join</h2>

    <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <div class ="errormsg" id ="errormsg4"></div><br>
    <input type="submit" name="join" id="join" value="Submit"   ><br><br>

</form>
```

Comment: plus 1 (currently don't have the reputation to vote up)

Comment: hi i am trying to implement your solution in jquery but its not working, can you help me out, thank... please see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707047/jquery-ajax-form-requires-2-clicks-to-submit